# HTML/CSS image not wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website and when I try make a wrapper for an image, nothing happens. The aim is to make a section with an image I can use as a background and the wrapper hold the content in order (centered etc).

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper {
    width:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <img src="img/animebreeze.jpg" alt="animeb-image">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
    </img>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in your HTML `</img>`

```
<section>
    <img src="img/animebreeze.jpg" alt="animeb-image">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
    </img>
</div> </section>
```

Should be

```
<section>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="img/animebreeze.jpg" alt="animeb-image">
    </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4mxyb3e/1/)

Comment: Hello, Thanks the image is working now, but sadly it doesn't center. Basically I want no horizontal scroll and want the image to be smaller in height and fill the whole screen in width (like a banner). I've tried doing margins/height and width but nothing happens? Sorry I'm new and just got  stuck here :/

Comment: made some changes in fiddle, try follow the change in your design and see if it works and if you have a live site link, past here to have closer look, here is the fiddle with changes http://jsfiddle.net/n4mxyb3e/2/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted and learnt how to do it for next time!

Answer (score 2):

Place the `img` tag inside the `image-wrapper`.

There is no closing tag for `<img>` tag.

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
      <div class="image-wrapper"><img src="img/animebreeze.jpg" alt="animeb-image"></div>
    </section>
```

You can try this way as well:

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper { background: url(img/animebreeze.jpg)no-repeat center center; }
```

Using a `background-image` in your CSS, you don't use the `<img>` tag now.